# Set link https protocol in wsdl

Tags: .net, wcf, iis, https, wsdl

I have a WCF service which is secured through the load balancer. So client connection is via `https` but the service itself is not `https` under IIS. This means that the links in the `wsdl` are not secure, and I believe this is what is causing our client problems.

e.g. in the `wsdl`

```
<xsd:import schemaLocation="http://blah.com/whatever.svc?xsd=xsd0"
            namespace="http://blah.com" />
```

Is there some way of configuring the service to output `https` links in the `wsdl`? Or any other suggestions?

Comment: What leads you to believe this is the problem? What kind of clients are you using? PHP? Most clients don't read the WSDL at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

Are you exposing the metadata through the behavior (ServiceMetadataBehavior), and in that case is HttpsGet set to true?

See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.description.servicemetadatabehavior.httpsgetenabled(v=vs.100).aspx